# Universal program argument/environment GUI launcher

Tags: user-interface, command-line, environment-variables, launch

I work on software that requires access to DLLs, usually wants environment variables set a certain way, and can take command line parameters. I'm generally opposed to setting/modifying system-wide environment variables for the purpose of launching these apps, since I might want to use different dependencies (different dlls), etc. and I don't want to accidentally get the wrong DLL loaded.

Up until now, I've been generating the visual studio .vcproj.user files and matching batch files from cmake ( [see here for my script](https://github.com/rpavlik/cmake-modules/blob/master/CreateLaunchers.cmake) ) that extends the path to include the path to my dlls, sets any other environment variables as needed, and launches the application, forwarding all the command line arguments.  (I do the same on Linux, but it's simpler because of RPATH). When we want to launch with a command line argument that wasn't just a file we could drop on the batch file, what we did is copy the batch file and edit the command to add our argument.  (It's all GUI applications, but config files/flags can be passed on the command line)

This has become quite a hassle for me and my colleagues, and we end up with a ton of batch files, named similarly and difficult to maintain. It's not really a great interface for starting but there's a lot of apps we either use or develop that are like this, so it's a common task.

My question is this: I'd like a nicer way to configure dynamic library search paths, process-local environment variables, working directory, executable, and arguments for starting a program than hand-editing a batch file every time.  I've done some digging to try to find one, but haven't been successful - "launcher" tends to bring me to "search-as-you-type" tools for frequently-used apps, and "command line argument" tends to find recommendations to use batch files.  (It's not a windows-specific issue, either, but the dynamic library path stuff is less problematic during the code/compile/run cycle)

I've made a quick mockup of what I'm envisioning: it seems like the kind of thing that has to exist somewhere. Do you know of a tool similar to this (preferably cross-platform, and open source is even better)? It doesn't need all bells and whistles I put in the mockup, but that's what I'd build if I had time to build it myself. Thanks!

[image: Quick mockup of my ideal tool]